# I have some question about Vue component structure

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

While studying Vue By self-taught, I faced some problem.

First, I bind some component by `new Vue ({el:" # id "})`.

And when I bind root component `<div id = "app">` by `new Vue ({el:" # app "})`,

It ruin what already was binding there.

My function and data in `new Vue ({el:" # id "})` didn't work anymore.

Am I doing the wrong design?

If so, how should I approach the problem?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div id="comp-a">
            <input type="text" v-model="message"/>
            {{message}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el : "#comp-a",
        data : {
            message : "message"
        }
    })
    new Vue({
        el : "#app"
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use component.
reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

```js
let comp_a=Vue.component('comp-a', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      message: ""
    }
  },
  template: ` <div><input type="text" v-model="message"/>
            {{message}}</div>`
});
let app = new Vue({
    el:"#app"

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <comp-a></comp-a>
</div>
```

If you want to component's html  code in html area. template can point to  by id. you can do following:

```js
let comp_a=Vue.component('comp-a', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      message: ""
    }
  },
  template: "#comp-a"
});

let app = new Vue({
    el:"#app"

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <comp-a></comp-a>
</div>

<template id="comp-a">
<div>
  <input type="text" v-model="message"/>
            {{message}}
 </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you! but, comp-a already contains components inside. Is it ok to wrap it once more with component?

Comment: In my project, comp-a already contains a list of components implemented in v-for and template.

Comment: comp-a did not contains any components so far. however comp-a can contains another components as well, event itself if you setup <slot> in the template property.reference: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: I have not seen a vue slot for the first time. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

VueJS does not work this way. You don't nest IDs. You could do this:

```
 <html>
 <head>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="app">

    </div>

    <div id="comp-a">
        {{message}}
    </div>
</body>
<script>
  new Vue({
    el : "#app"
  })
  new Vue({
    el : "#comp-a",
    data : {
        message : "message"
    }
  })
</script>
```

But even that approach has problems. You really should have only one matching VueJS area.

The only reason to have two is if you really have two applications running on the same html file. I have never seen a reason to do that.

Comment: I make a small page as a hobby and try to put it on a tumbler. So I can not use the backend .... I'll have to solve the problem in a different way. Thank you.